# Use crunch to generate wordlist template

Tags: passwords, crunch

I am trying to use `crunch` to generate a wordlist in the following template: The word `password` then one digit (`0`-`9`) and then one of the special characters `*,?,$,!`.

The output should be like this:

first: `password0*`
last:  `password9!`

This is where I am at:

```
crunch 10 10 + + + !$?* -t password%^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$`, `?` and `*` are special in many shells; `!` is special in some shells, in some circumstances. Single-quote.

And, if you want `password0*` to be first and `password9!` to be last, `*` should be first and `!` should be last in the charset.

```
crunch 10 10 + + + '*$?!' -t password%^
```